# How to store java Calendar time in MySql timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I was implementing Java "Forgot password functionality" and needed to add an expiring time to the reset password page. I created a Calendar class object for time and added 30 minutes to it. Code below:

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(utilDate);
cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);
```

And used in DB query as:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO forgotpasskeytab (keyId, emailid, expireIn) VALUES ('"+uniqueID+"','"+emailid+"','"+cal.getTime()+"')";
```

the **expireIn** column in my `forgotpasskeytab` table is of type `timestamp`.

I am getting the following error while running:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: 'Fri Oct 09 20:39:14 IST 2015' for column 'expireIn' at row 1

Is there any other better way to save expiring time in mysql DB table?

Answer (score 3):

Stop generating your SQL by concatenating each part together! This is prone to [SQL injection](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-in-java-using-prepared-callable-statement) and is considered a very bad practice.

You need to use a [`PreparedStatement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with `?` placeholders ([tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)).

Assuming we have a `Connection` instance inside the variable `connection`:

```
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO forgotpasskeytab (keyId, emailid, expireIn) VALUES (?,?,?)")) {
    ps.setLong(1, uniqueID); // the first value is replaced by uniqueID as Long
    ps.setLong(2, emailid); // the second value is replaced by emailid as Long
    ps.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()));  // the third value is replaced by the timestamp of the calendar
    ps.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: Dang, you beat me by a few seconds. FYI: `cal.getTimeInMillis()` is better in this case. ;-)

Comment: thank you for your guidance but i want to know why practise .getTime() TWICE in "cal.getTIme().getTime()" ??

Comment: @HarshVardhan Because `cal.getTime()` returns a `Date` so we need to call `getTime()` again on this `Date` to have a `long` value. But it is possible to use the simpler `cal.getTimeInMillis()`.

Answer (score 2):

**Never** use string concatenation to insert text values in SQL, unless you want to leave yourself open to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, allowing hackers to delete or steal all your data. Use `PrepareStatement` instead.

This also helps with date/time values:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO forgotpasskeytab (keyId, emailid, expireIn) VALUES (?,?,?)";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setString(1, uniqueID); // or setInt?
    stmt.setString(2, emailid); // or setInt?
    stmt.setTimestamp(3, new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTimeInMillis()));
    stmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

Comment: I see you also prefer to write `new java.sql.Timestamp` instead of importing `Timestamp` :)

Comment: @Tunaki Actually, that was a more because I was going for `java.sql.Date` at first where the difference had to be documented.

Answer (score 1):

The mysql format is: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(cal.getTime());
```

However I agree that prepared statement is a better metod

Answer (score 0):

In order for your query to work you need a timestamp instance of java.sql.Timestamp and your's 'cal.getTime()' returns java.util.Date instance which is wrong.

So, following query should work for your case:

```
String query = "INSERT INTO forgotpasskeytab (keyId, emailid, expireIn) VALUES ('"+uniqueID+"','"+emailid+"','"+ new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTime()) +"')";
```